# Error in factor_list with polynomial containing complex exponentials

Tags: sympy, complex-numbers, factorization

I want to make a factor list out an expressions and found a weird behaviour in a special case, which I do not understand. One example would be:

The polynomial contains a pre-factor of exp(-4*pi*I/7) and this factor sometimes makes problems. Removing the negative sign makes it work. It works also with the negative sign when used in a different expression. Below is an example with three expressions

> ```
> import sympy as sym
> q=sym.Symbol("q")
>
> # this example works
> y1=3*(sym.exp(4*sym.I*sym.pi/7)*q - 1)*sym.exp(2)
> print( sym.factor_list(y1,q) )
>
> # this one not
> y2=3*(sym.exp(-4*sym.I*sym.pi/7)*q - 1)*sym.exp(2)
> print( sym.factor_list(y2,q) )
>
> # this one works too
> y3=3*(sym.exp(-4*sym.I*sym.pi/7)*q - 1)**2*sym.exp(2)
> print( sym.factor_list(y3,q) )
> ```

For the second example I get the error

```
sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: a polynomial expected, got (3*q*exp(-4*I*pi/7) - 3)*exp(2)
```

For the third expression I get

```
(3*exp(2), [(exp(6*I*pi/7), 1), (q - exp(4*I*pi/7), 2)])
```

but the first entry (exp(6*I*pi/7), 1) does not contain the variable q

Any ideas whats wrong with the second example and why exp(6*I*pi/7) in the third example appears not with the constant factor 3*exp(2)
thanks

Comment: You can use `frac=True` for the second example

Comment: With frac=True I get (3*exp(2), [(q*exp(4*I*pi/7) - 1, 1)], []) and
(3*exp(2), [(q - exp(4*I*pi/7), 1)], [(exp(4*I*pi/7), 1)]) and
(3*exp(2), [(exp(6*I*pi/7), 1), (q - exp(4*I*pi/7), 2)], []). What is the meaning of the three entries per example and what is the meaning of frac=True? They all look somehow quite different. thanks